# Groovy + WebDriver: how to use a variable in xpath?

Tags: xpath, groovy, webdriver

This code works:

```
MyField = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select/option[contains(text(), '10.11.12.13')]"))
MyField.click()
```

This code doesn't work (the element is not selected)

```
ClientHost = '10.11.12.13'
MyField = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select/option[contains(text(), ClientHost)]"))
MyField.click()
```

**Question: how to pass a variable value to xpath?**

Thanks,
Racoon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
 myField = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select/option[contains(text(), '$ClientHost')]")
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! The first solution ('" + ClientHost + "') works too.

Comment: That was the second solution, and it is not ideomatic groovy. glad your problem is solved tho :)

Comment: Yes, you're right. That was the second, and your solution is more ideomatic, so I marked it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
MyField = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select/option[contains(text(), '" + ClientHost + "')]"))
```

Your code doesn't work because your variable isn't interpreted as such in the string, it is seen a string 'ClientHost'. You have to concatenate the variable into the string for it to work the way you want.

Comment: Thanks, it works! The second solution ('$ClientHost') works too.